# Java Strings empty string handling

Tags: java, string

I have a Java code that should print nothing if no-element string is passed.Currently,my method is passing all tests but the one with no-element string.It gives me error.Code is below.Any suggestions are welcome.

```
public static void printLetters(String text)
{

System.out.print(text.charAt(0));

for(int i=1;i<text.length();i++)
{
    System.out.print("-" + text.charAt(i));
}

System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your exception pops up on your line

```
System.out.print(text.charAt(0));
```

If you pass an empty string the code will try to access a char at `0`. In the empty string there is no 0th char.

A check like this might suit you:

```
public static void printLetters(String text)
{
    if (text != null && text.length() != 0)
    {
        System.out.print(text.charAt(0));

        for(int i=1;i<text.length();i++)
        {
            System.out.print("-" + text.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: `if(text.length()!=0)` can be replaced with `if (!text.isEmpty())`

Comment: I don't think it will make a huge difference performance wise, but you are right to say that they reach equivalent boolean values.

Comment: Yes, performance will be similar but it would be easier to read and maintain such code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be giving you giving you [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) if you pass `null` because you are de-referencing `text` before checking if it is `null` or not and de-referencing null results in `NPE`.

```
if(text != null){
return;
}
```

For empty String test you can do the following

```
if(text.isEmpty()){
System.out.println(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an if statement to check if the `text` variable is null, if so return.

Also you can remove the first `System.out.print(text.charAt(0));` and just change so the for loop starts at `i = 0`

```
public static void printLetters(String text)
{
    if (text == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.print(text.charAt(i) + ",");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have this problem is because if you have a string which has a null pointer the charAt(0) will automatically throw a NullPointerException. Try to evaluate first if the string has null pointet, if it's not then you can go ahead and use charAt(0) and the other operations.